# Python Unittest: How to tell teamcity that test have failed

Tags: python, teamcity

I have test cases in unittest framework. Have integrated them with teamcity.
Teamcity gives success even if my testcase fail. I Think, it is so since my unittest process exit with code 0 which is success for teamcity. I have integrated report, which show test failure. What needs to be done, so that teamcity also show failure if test fails.

code:

```
import unittest

class Login(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_002_login_failure(self):
        assert 1==2
```

Answer (score 2):

You should prefer to use the `unittest` [assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) so for example

```
self.assertEqual(1, 2)
```

Also you can use the [`teamcity-messages`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/teamcity-messages) module to emit test messages the TeamCity will handle appropriately. Then you could change your `main` (if you have one) to something like the following

```
import teamcity
from teamcity.unittestpy import TeamcityTestRunner

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if teamcity.is_running_under_teamcity():
        runner = TeamcityTestRunner()
    else:
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

Comment: self.assertEqual(1, 2) also gives success in teamcity. Also, I am already using runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner for report generation.